# How can I track down an Out of Memory exception?

Tags: delphi

The stack looks like this

```
:7576b9bc KERNELBASE.RaiseException + 0x58
:671c57ad ; F:\invariant data - not DropBox\3rd_party_vcl\MAD collection\madExcept\Dlls\madExcept32.dll
:671c953f ; F:\invariant data - not DropBox\3rd_party_vcl\MAD collection\madExcept\Dlls\madExcept32.dll
:71a80013 
System._ReallocMem(???,???)
:0040497d @ReallocMem + $45
System._DynArraySetLength
IdIOHandler.TIdIOHandler.ReadFromSource(True,-2,True)
IdIOHandler.TIdIOHandler.ReadLn(#$A,-1,16384,$D3B6FF0)
IdIOHandler.TIdIOHandler.ReadLn(nil)
IdCmdTCPServer.TIdCmdTCPServer.ReadCommandLine($7CC1AFB4)
IdCmdTCPServer.TIdCmdTCPServer.DoExecute($7CC1AFB4)
IdContext.TIdContext.Run
IdTask.TIdTask.DoRun
IdThread.TIdThreadWithTask.Run
IdThread.TIdThread.Execute
:004ccf91 HookedTThreadExecute + $2D
System.Classes.ThreadProc($7A486F84)
System.ThreadWrapper($7BFBEFF8)
:004cce73 CallThreadProcSafe + $F
:004ccee0 ThreadExceptFrame + $3C
:7559339a kernel32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x12
:76f39ef2 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x63
:76f39ec5 ntdll.RtlInitializeExceptionChain + 0x36
```

none of which is my code. It loks like INDY code, but I realize that if my code is buggy then the exception can still be thrown somewhere elase as a result of me taking all the memory.

I am running MAD Except with leak detection on.  If I run for w hile and close the program, it reports no leak. If I leave the program running for a few hours I get the out of memory exception.

I only have two calls to Create(), both are in timer handlers and I have set the timer duration to one second in order to stres stest. The handlers are pretty simple and always Free() the created object.

Is there anything else I can look at, apart from the code of the timer handlers?

Here's the code if anyone really needs to see it ... these are the only two palces where I `Create()` an object ...

```
procedure TMainForm.ServerAliveTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);

   var timestamp : LongInt;
       ADConnection: TADConnection;
       theDialogForm : TDialogFormForm;
begin
   ServerAliveTimer.Enabled := False;
   TraceInfo('ServerAliveTimer expired after ' + IntToStr(ServerAliveTimer.Interval div 1000) + ' seconds');

   try
      ADConnection := TADConnection.Create(Self);
      ADConnection.DriverName := 'mysql';
      ADConnection.Params.Add('Server=' + MAIN_STOREROOM_IP_ADDRESS);
      ADConnection.Params.Add('Database=XXX');
      ADConnection.Params.Add('User_Name=XXX');
      ADConnection.Params.Add('Password=XXX');
      ADConnection.Params.Add('Port=3306');
      ADConnection.Connected := True;

   except
      on E : Exception do
      begin
         StopAllTimers();

         TraceError('Database error. Failed to create ADO connection');

         ADConnection.Free();

         theDialogForm := TDialogFormForm.Create(Nil);
         theDialogForm.ShowTheForm('Database problem'+#13+#10+''+#13+#10+
                                   E.ClassName+#13+#10+
                                   E.Message);

         StopTheApplication();
         Exit;
      end;
   end;

   if isMainStoreRoom then
   begin
      CheckIfStoreRoomIsAlive(SECONDARY_STOREROOM_IP_ADDRESS);
   end
   else
   begin
      CheckIfStoreRoomIsAlive(MAIN_STOREROOM_IP_ADDRESS);
   end;

   // Now, update our own timestamp
   try
      timestamp  := GetCurrentUnixTimeStamp();
      ADConnection.ExecSQL('UPDATE server_status SET alive_timestamp="' + IntToStr(timestamp) + '" WHERE ip_address="' + ipAddress + '"');

   except
      on E : Exception do
      begin
         TraceError('Database error. Failed to upate timestamp for ip_address = "' +
                        ipAddress + ' in table "server_status"' + #13#10#13#10 +
                        E.ClassName+#13+#10+
                        E.Message);
         ADConnection.Free();
         Exit;
      end;
   end;

   ADConnection.Free();
   ServerAliveTimer.Enabled := True;
end;     // ServerAliveTimerTimer()
```

and

```
procedure TMainForm.CheckEndOfScheduleTimerTimer(Sender: TObject);
   var ADConnection : TADConnection;
       ADQuery : TADQuery;
       secondsSinceMidnight : LongInt;
       timeNow : LongInt;
       today : LongInt;
       checkoutDay : LongInt;
       checkoutExpireTime : LongInt;
       theDialogForm : TDialogFormForm;
       rfidTag : String;
       i : integer;
begin
   CheckEndOfScheduleTimer.Enabled := False;

   ADConnection := Nil;
   ADQuery := Nil;

   try
      TraceInfo('CheckEndOfScheduleTimer expired after ' + IntToStr(CheckEndOfScheduleTimer.Interval div 1000) + ' seconds');

      secondsSinceMidnight := GetSecondsSinceMidnight();
      timeNow := GetCurrentUnixTimeStamp();
      today := timeNow - secondsSinceMidnight;

      ADConnection := TADConnection.Create(nil);
      ADConnection.DriverName := 'mysql';
      ADConnection.Params.Add('Server=' + MAIN_STOREROOM_IP_ADDRESS);
      ADConnection.Params.Add('Database=XXX');
      ADConnection.Params.Add('User_Name=XXX');
      ADConnection.Params.Add('Password=XXX');
      ADConnection.Params.Add('Port=3306');
      ADConnection.Connected := True;

      ADQuery := TADQuery.Create(ADConnection);
      ADQuery.Connection := ADConnection;
      ADQuery.Open('SELECT * FROM tagged_chemicals');
      ADQuery.FetchAll();

      for i := 0 to Pred(ADQuery.Table.Rows.Count) do
      begin
         if ADQuery.Table.Rows[i].GetData('checked_out') = 'N' then
            Continue;

         checkoutDay        := ADQuery.Table.Rows[i].GetData('checkout_day');
         checkoutExpireTime := ADQuery.Table.Rows[i].GetData('checkout_expire_time');

         if (today + secondsSinceMidnight) > (checkoutDay + checkoutExpireTime) then
         begin
            rfidTag := ADQuery.Table.Rows[i].GetData('rfid_tag');

            TraceInfo('End of pouring time for RFID tag (' + IntToStr(secondsSinceMidnight) + ' seconds after midnight');

            ADConnection.ExecSQL('UPDATE tagged_chemicals ' +
                                    'SET checked_out="N", ' +
                                        'checkout_day="0", ' +
                                        'checkout_expire_time="0" ' +
                                 ' WHERE  rfid_tag="' + rfidTag + '"');
         end;
      end;

      ADQuery.Free();
      ADConnection.Free();

   except
      On E: Exception do
      begin
         ADQuery.Free();
         ADConnection.Free();
         TraceError('Databse exception (' + E.ClassName + ') : "' + E.Message + '"');

         theDialogForm := TDialogFormForm.Create(Nil);
         theDialogForm.ShowTheForm('Database error when checking end of pouring time'+#13+#10+''+#13+#10+
                    E.ClassName+#13+#10+
                    E.Message);
      end;
   end;

   CheckEndOfScheduleTimer.Enabled := True;
end;     // CheckEndOfScheduleTimerTimer()
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not having some unhandled exception between the two try..except in `ServerAliveTimerTimer`? Specifically in the call to `CheckIfStoreRoomIsAlive` or `isMainStoreRoom` (not sure if this one is a function or a boolean).

Comment: +1 A good point. I will throw a TRY around the whole function body.  It's 9pm here so I will run it overnight and get back to you. Thanks very much for the suggestion.

Comment: Indy is trying to allocate memory to hold whatever it's reading from the socket. Maybe the other end of the socket has sent a request that claims to be inordinately large, and your program simply tries to allocate memory for all that. It might be a bug in the other program, or it might be that the program is maliciously (and successfully) trying to crash your program. You can use Wireshark to see what data arrives on the socket.

Comment: Try using the [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027) tools VMMap and Process Explorer this should tell you where the memory is going.

Comment: +1 for this question. It is interesting to see how other developers deal with these things - even if for the schadenfreude value only :-)

Comment: @RobKennedy +1, but the data sent is never more than a dozen bytes.  I think that something else in my app gobbled all the memory, leaving none for Indy which coincidentally took the blame.

Comment: @Mike, that comment belongs as an answer. It might not solve the specific issue at hand, but that's OK since if that were the question, it would be too localized and get closed. Your comment answers the question of how to track out-of-memory problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb545027) tools VMMap and Process Explorer this should tell you where the memory is going.

Comment: +1 I still haven't tracked it down yet, but VMMap is an impressive tool. Thanks

Comment: I never ever tracked it out down; a few code changes & rebuilds and it went away. But VMMap deserves the answer.